# Makefile - run command as a chain

Tags: bash, makefile

I would like to run the following script  but separate it to targets

```
ENV1=x ENV2=y ./node_modules/.bin/start-test 'npm start' 3000 \
              'docker run....' 3001 'ENV3=x npm run some script'
```

Now my makefile is: (and it's working fine). `make test`

```
test:
    ENV1=x ENV2=y ./node_modules/.bin/start-test  'npm start' 3000 \
    'docker run....' 3001 \ 
    'ENV3=x npm run some script'
```

I would like to separate it into something like:

```
test: run-x run-a run-b

run-x:  ENV1=x ENV2=y ./node_modules/.bin/start-test  'npm start' 3000 
run-a:  'docker run....' 3001
run-b: 'ENV3=x npm run some script'
```

So to run it as a chain of commands, but the result is that run-x will run without chaining the next 2 commands as a string.

Comment: I am unclear about why you want these steps as separate targets. Do they make sense when executed in separation?

Comment: @Vroomfondel  more readable and cleaner 
and also for re-use in other targets

Comment: Your last wish can't be fulfilled by the `make` genie, as it can't place generic rules in an arbitrary place in a dependency chain. If `run-x` has to be done before `run-a` then you must, at some point in time (i.e. the current `make` run) make it explicit that `run-a` depends on `run-b`. There is no way to have a non-connected rule `run-a` in a makefile and give the order "`run-x` then `run-a`" somewhere else - there is no other place than the dependency list of `run-a` where it can be noted that `run-x` has to be executed beforehand.

Comment: Adding prerequisite to a target and running it with `make -j 4` results in each prerequisite to be executed alongside the other. Are you sure that they can run in any order?

Comment: Thus, what @Vroomfondel checks out :p Also `ENV1` and `ENV2` are not available in the `run-b` target. Your first makefile will have somewhat the same behaviour if you would remove the slashes `\` from the command.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me as-asked.  The original is one single command, where different arguments are passed to a single script `start-test`.  One assumes that the `start-test` script will run these commands for you, probably within some sort of test context.  I can't see how you can break them out into separate rules in make, which are necessarily run in separate shells.  Put another way, if you can type these three commands individually at three different shell prompts and have that work, then make can do the same thing.  If you can't do it, then make can't do it either.